# How to get top down forecasts using `hts::combinef()`?

Tags: r, time-series, hierarchy, forecasting

I am trying to compare forecast reconciliation methods from the `hts` package on previously existing forecasts.  The `forecast.gts` function is not available to me since there is no computationally tractable way to create a user defined function that returns the values in a forecast object.  Because of this, I am using the `combinef()` function in the package to redistribute the forecasts.  I have been able to work of the proper `weights` to get the `wls` and `nseries` methods, and the `ols` version is the default.  I was able to get the "bottom up" method using:

```
# Creates sample forecasts, taken from `combinef()` example
library(hts)
h <- 12
ally <- aggts(htseg1)
allf <- matrix(NA, nrow = h, ncol = ncol(ally))
for(i in 1:ncol(ally))
    allf[,i] <- forecast(auto.arima(ally[,i]), h = h, PI = FALSE)$mean
allf <- ts(allf, start = 51)
# create the weight vector
numTS <- ncol(allf) # Get the total number of series
numBaseTS <- sum(tail(htseg1$nodes, 1)[[1]]) # Get the number of bottom level series
# Create weights of 0 for all aggregate ts and 1 for the base level
weightVals <- c(rep(0, numTS - numBaseTS), rep(1, numBaseTS))
y.f <- combinef(allf, htseg1$nodes, weights = weightVals)
```

I was hoping that something like making the first weight `1` and the rest `0` might give me one of the three top down forecast, but that just results in a bunch of `0`s or `NaN` values depending on how you try to look at it.

```
combinef(allf, htseg1$nodes, weights = c(1, rep(0, numTS - 1)))
```

I know the top down methods aren't the hardest thing to compute manually, and I can just write a function to do that, but are there any tools in the `hts` package that can help with this? I'd like to keep the data format consistent to simplify my analysis.  Most specifically, I would like to get the "top down forcasted proportions" or `tdfp` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions to reconcile the forecasts using the "top-down" method are currently not exported. Probably I should export them to make the "top-down" results as tractable as `combinef()` in the next version. The workaround is as follows:

```
hts:::TdFp(allf, nodes = htseg1$nodes)
```

Hope it helps.