# How to do top down forecasted proportions for hts objects with 2 levels?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, hierarchical

I had previously asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058495/how-to-get-top-down-forecasts-using-htscombinef) trying to get top down forecasted proportions forecast recombination using the `hts` package.  The solution there works great for multilevel hierarchies, however I have found I get an error when I try to use the solution on a two level hierarchy.

```
library(hts)
# Create the hierarchy
newhts <- hts(htseg1$bts, list(ncol(htseg1$bts)))
# forecast creation adapted from the `combinef()` example
h <- 12
ally <- aggts(newhts)
allf <- matrix(NA, nrow = h, ncol = ncol(ally))
for(i in 1:ncol(ally))
    allf[,i] <- forecast(auto.arima(ally[,i]), h = h, PI = FALSE)$mean
allf <- ts(allf, start = 51)
# Earo Wang's solution to my previous question
hts:::TdFp(allf, nodes = htseg1$nodes)
```

> Error in *.default(fcasts[, 1L], prop) : time-series/vector length mismatch

The problem seems to arise because a two level hierarchy skips the last `if` conditional with the condition `if (l.levels > 2L)`.  The last statement of this conditional multiplies includes a piece where `prop` is multiplied by the time series `flist[[k + 1L]]`, which converts `prop` into a time series matrix.  When this statement is skipped, `prop` remains a regular matrix causing the error when the time series vector `fcasts[, 1L]` is multiplied by the matrix `prop`.

I understand that `TdFp` is a non exported function and therefore may not be as robust as the other functions in the package, but is there any way around this problem?  Since it is a relatively simple case, I can code a solution myself, but since `hts::forecast.hts()` can handle two level hierarchies for `method = "tdfp"`, I thought there might be a nice clean solution.

Comment: as you spotted, it's a bug in the `TdFp` function. I haven't found a workaround for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: I've just realised the workaround is simply deleting `allf <- ts(allf, start = 51)`, as `TdFp` only deals with matrix.

Comment: @marbel I don't know what you are talking about, I have not edited this question nor do I have an answer readily available since I asked this over a year ago.  If I found a solution, I normally self answer so most likely I didn't have an answer a year ago either.